# Nvidia Optimus on Linux (not bumblebee)

Tags: linux, nvidia-graphics-card, optimus

Edit: The chosen answer did not solve it for me but was the closest and maybe it could be of help to others.

I am using Ubuntu 18/Mint 19 and I have been looking around for weeks for a solution to this. I am using a Lenovo Y720 gaming laptop with an i7 and a GTX 1060 with Optimus. Has anyone managed to find anything to get Optimus running?
Currently my issues are:

- Overheating 90+ celcius when gaming, 50 when idle
- No HDMI audio
- Extremely low battery life
- Screen tearing

I tried Nvidia xrun and primerun from GitHub, no luck. Tried bumblebee and it couldn't open any program at all except chrome. I am using the Nvidia proprietary drivers right now, driver 390.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing possible solutions for your HDMI audio & screen tearing issues:

1. **No HDMI audio**:
   A possible fix would be to check your Sound settings of Ubuntu. While your HDMI is plugged in, try opening your Sound settings and check for **Output** devices. There should be the HDMI / DisplayPort option, if it is configured to use mode **Analog Stereo**, switch it to **HDMI Output Stereo**. Replug your HDMI cable and see if it works. There are other possible solutions [here](https://itsfoss.com/how-to-fix-no-sound-through-hdmi-in-external-monitor-in-ubuntu/), if you haven't tried them already.
2. **Screen tearing**: This is a known issue with NVIDIA's proprietary drivers, however, despite this fact, those drivers are still the way to go unless you need to switch to Intel, since there is a noticeable performance boost. NVIDIA haven't provided any fix yet, but here is a possible solution, as described by [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA_Optimus):
   **Note**: `xorg-xandr` package must be installed alongside the NVIDIA driver for this to work.
   Check your version of `xorg-server` and update it if needed, the required version is (>) 1.19.
   The linux kernel's version must be 4.5 or higher.
   Since nvidia 364.16, the [**DRM Kernel Mode Setting**](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA#DRM_kernel_mode_setting) is supported. To enable it, you must add the following kernel parameter: `nvidia-drm.modeset=1`, as well as add the following modules to the **initramfs modules**: `nvidia`, `nvidia_modeset`, `nvidia_uvm`, and `nvidia_drm`.
   To add the DRM kernel parameter permanently in Ubuntu (see [KernelBootParameters @ Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters)), edit `/etc/default/grub` and add the `nvidia-drm.modeset=1` parameter in the quotes of the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` setting (add space between each kernel parameter). After that, run `sudo update-grub` to update the GRUB configuration file.
   To add the modules to initramfs , edit `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` and add each module on a new line. Then, update the initramfs with the following command: `update-initramfs -u`. The `-u` options tells `update-initramfs` to update your existing initramfs and not build it anew. The `modules` file should look like this:

```
# List of modules that you want to include in your initramfs.
# They will be loaded at boot time in the order below.
#
# Syntax:  module_name [args ...]
#
# You must run update-initramfs(8) to effect this change.
#
# Examples:
#
# raid1
# sd_mod
nvidia
nvidia_modeset
nvidia_uvm
nvidia_drm
```

About the overheating issue:
I doubt it's driver-related. Depends how heavy games you play of course, however, Lenovo's internal cooling systems are not enough to handle an i7 CPU and a GTX 1060 on a laptop. Such temperatures are to be expected, although they are not good for the GPU itself and a fix should be searched for. I suggest you use an external cooler.

And about the battery life:
Especially when using the NVIDIA proprietary drive (which only uses the NVIDIA GPU and disables Intel) I cannot say that this is not expected, since a GTX 1060 consumes a lot of power (120W, according to [NVIDIA GTX 1060 specifications](https://www.geforce.co.uk/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-1060/specifications)). Especially when under high load, both the CPU and the GPU will be taking a toll on your battery.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 1: The audio is not under settings, it does not pop up. 2: I will try that. 3: The cooling system is more than enough, I never got more than 75-80 celcius on Windows, on much more demanding things, 90+ on Cs go is insane. The battery life is about 5 hours on Windows, 1 hour on Linux, these are on idle of course.